# Help with this MOSFET comparator

Tags: mosfet, comparator

So I'm building something and I figured I needed a mid-voltage Comparator or symmetrical Schmitt Trigger (by losing the MOSFET half of the V2 side). For reasons of "just-because", I decided it should be MOSFET based. So I thought I wouldn't run to any problem, but just when I started, there are values that popped up I don't think is correct.

Below is the stripped-down version:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgNbgl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, I'm just wondering as to why CMP1 would be "15V", as M1 should not even switch on as the gate is less electropositive than the source.

EDIT:

This is just the MOSFET implementation of this BJT comparator:
[image]

EDIT:

Also, I gave the title "CMOS Comparator", what I meant was "MOSFET Comparator". I corrected it now.

Comment: To clarify your schematic a bit I suggest removing input generators and labeling the inputs. I don't think you can make a comparator with only two transistors anyway.

Comment: I'm starting to think people in this site lack imagination. Sure I'm not showing you the whole project, but this one is just a weeny, tiny, small step from the previous...

Comment: They don't lack for imagination.  They've got more experience, and much MORE imagination, and so can (usually) see multiple things that might be in or around your circuit if it isn't complete enough.  Rather than provide an answer that might be based on a different view of your problem, they ask for clarification.

Comment: ^ this. And please note that your first circuit is not a mos implementation of the second, it's just vaguely similar.

Comment: The first lacks 2 more PMOS from the original sketch, I deleted them to simplify and point the first snag. Though, of course, the V_DD needs to be greater than any other voltage input. I was gonna fix that later on...

Comment: I mentioned above "tripped-down version". It should've been "stripped-down version"

Comment: Or, I could use 2 depletion NMOS rather than 2 PMOS. Switches faster and actually can have a current-sourcing "high" for CMP1 and CMP2 if V1=V2, which I'm not sure the BJT implementation can do.

Comment: My stripped down version answer is "Your circuit does not work because of reasons.". Good luck!

Comment: Still doesn't answer the question as to why M1 switches "on".

Comment: M1 does not switch on.

Comment: Unfortunately, M1 does seem to turn on.  CMP1 shows 15V when using the simulator.  It also show 15Volts in the simulator when there's a 1K resistor from CMP1 to ground.  So, maybe something wrong with the circuit or the simulator?

Answer (score 2):

First, your stripped-down circuit is pretty worthless without specifying the loads on the M1 and M2 drains.

Second, even though the Vgs of M1 is -5, the only current available at the drain will be leakage currents from the source. Since the drain is floating, regardless of the amplitude of those leakage currents, since there is no alternative current path, a voltage reading at the drain will equal the voltage at the source - in this case, 15 volts.

Comment: Never considered Drain-Source leakage, good thing that CircuitLab also simulates that.

Answer (score 2):

Mosfets without all three terminals connected do not work, unless you want to use them for the body diode or as a capacitor.

Adding names to nodes in a SPICE simulation is *not* like attaching a real voltmeter. Real voltmeters have input impedances that aren’t infinite. Adding a name to a SPICE node does not connect anything to it unless some other node also has the same name.

The circuits you show are not complete enough to even simulate. They don’t work in real life either, since you can’t even measure the voltages you purport to measure - otherwise you’d need to actually load those labeled nodes with at least a DVM input impedance. The voltmeter symbols in CircuitLab have an input impedance parameter that comes handy for that.

And finally, usual Schmitt trigger’s don’t use capacitors to store state. The circuit you have stripped down is an oscillator, not a Schmitt trigger. A Google search for CMOS Schmitt triggers provides useful circuits. The CD4007 application circuits in the datasheet have a Schmitt trigger implementation example IIRC too.

Answer (score 1):

Explanation to why M1 voltage might show 15 V is that the simulators work on equation basis and need a complete circuit.

The measurement point CMP1, say acting like voltmeter, will offer a very high resistance path (e.g. 100 MΩ typical in multisim) to ground.

Had there been something connected in parallel to the CMP1 VM, the reading would be 0 V.

But in absence of that, the lower resistance path is the High-Res VM path in comparison to the open circuit otherwise. This is still much higher than what the simulated MOSFET offers, say around 1-10 MΩ.

Hence all of 15 V drops through the voltmeter itself.

Having said that, the MOSFET is still not on because there will be (for all practical significance) no current flowing through. If a current sensor is connected in path of 15 V and M1, it should read no more than few pA (picoampere).